# Is the `alignof` of a struct always the maximum `alignof` of its constituents?

Tags: c

I've noticed from playing around with simple examples that `alignof(struct_name)` is always the `alignof` of the maximum `alignof` of its struct constituents. Is this always (or almost always) the case?

Comment: Almost always — definitely.  Always — maybe not if someone got enthusiastic and specified a more stringent (larger) `_Alignas` value than necessary.  I reserve judgement on whether that means the `alignof` is the same as the `alignas` or not.

Comment: And there are definitely good reasons to do so. Aligning to cache line boundaries, aligning for SIMD instructions, …

Comment: I think I've heard of systems where all 4-byte structs have align 4, even if their members are all align 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the `alignof` of a struct always the maximum `alignof` of its constituents?

The `alignof` macro expands to the `_Alignof` operator, which computes the alignment requirement of its operand.  Most aspects of how alignment requirements are determined are implementation-defined, so in that sense it is not safe to assume that your proposition always or even usually holds.

The pattern you observed is nevertheless common, however.  In order for an implementation to ensure that every member of every instance of a given structure type is aligned according to the alignment requirement of that member's type, the implementation must choose an alignment requirement for the overall structure type that is at least as large as the maximum alignment requirement of any of its members.  On the other hand, choosing the smallest possible alignment requirement  contributes to efficient use of memory.  The combination of those leads to the alignment behavior you observed.

I reiterate, however, that alignment requirements are for the most part implementation-defined.  Even excluding from consideration the effects of the `_Alignas` operator, implementations are not obligated to choose structure alignment requirements according to your pattern.  For instance, an implementation could choose to assign (at least) the maximum fundamental alignment to every structure type, regardless of its member types.

Ultimately, however, one has to wonder why you care.  It is rare, albeit not unheard-of, that you need to know or should depend on the alignment requirements of your types.  Where you do want a specific alignment requirement, you are much better off declaring it directly than trying to use members' types to influence it.

Comment: why the implementation usually choose an alignment requirement for the overall structure type that is at least as large as the maximum alignment requirement of any of its members?

Comment: @Linh, suppose a structure has a member with a 64-bit alignment requirement, but the structure itself is attributed a 32-bit alignment requirement.  There are then twice as many addresses where the structure can start than there are where the member can start.  Necessarily, then, half (at least) of the structure start addresses result in the member being misaligned.

Comment: I agree that the alignment requirement for a structure must at least equal to the biggest alignment requirement of its members. Since the alignment requirement is the number of bytes between successive addresses at which objects of this type can be allocated, thus, I think the alignment requirement of a structure should be at least equal to structure size. So that the structure's objects do not overlap each other.

Comment: @Linh, it is true that if a structure type had an alignment requirement equal to its size, then meaningfully distinct objects of that type could not ever overlap, but that is neither the purpose nor the common use of an alignment requirement. It is not necessary for ensuring that objects of the same type do not overlap, and in practice, *no* compiler employs a general rule of giving all structure types' alignment requirements equal to their size.  Alignment requirements are entirely about data alignment.  That is, laying out objects in memory for efficient access.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've written some C++ code to experiment with alignment concept. It's as you said. The alignment is not necessary to at least equal to the object size (if doing so, it would waste some memory between successive objects). Thus, it's more efficient to have offset between successive objects as small as possible. In general, offset % alignment-requirement = 0 and the offset as small as possible.

Comment: @Linh, it is not merely a general rule, but rather a practical requirement for every type's alignment requirement to evenly divide its size.  Otherwise, arrays of objects of that type could not be formed without some of the elements being misaligned.  This is one of the reasons that some structures are laid out with unnamed padding.